# Why use "while" in the await method of AQS(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer)

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

In the [await](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.ConditionObject.html#await--) method of AQS ([AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html)):
I want to know the meaning of `while` in `while (!isOnSyncQueue(node)) {`

I think that if this node is woken up normally  (without being interrupted), It will definitely be moved to the sync queue after the signal method is executed by another thread, and then woken up by executing the unlock method in another thread.

So there could be a situation where a node is waking up normally, but not in the sync queue? If that's not possible, I think `if` should be used here instead of `while`

```java
public final void await() throws InterruptedException {
    if (Thread.interrupted())
        throw new InterruptedException();
    Node node = addConditionWaiter();
    int savedState = fullyRelease(node);
    int interruptMode = 0;
    while (!isOnSyncQueue(node)) {
        LockSupport.park(this);
        if ((interruptMode = checkInterruptWhileWaiting(node)) != 0)
            break;
    }
    if (acquireQueued(node, savedState) && interruptMode != THROW_IE)
        interruptMode = REINTERRUPT;
    if (node.nextWaiter != null) // clean up if cancelled
        unlinkCancelledWaiters();
    if (interruptMode != 0)
        reportInterruptAfterWait(interruptMode);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wakeups come in two flavours. The usual kind and the [spurious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) kind. This code:

```
while (!isOnSyncQueue(node)) {
    ...
}
```

Keeps looping until `isOnSyncQueue(node)` returns `false` and is a `while` instead of an `if`, because the wake up might be spurious and not because the condition being waited for has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!isOnSyncQueue(node)) {
    LockSupport.park(this);
    if ((interruptMode = checkInterruptWhileWaiting(node)) != 0)
        break;
}
```

What this does is execute the commands inside the pair of curly braces {}, until `isOnSyncQueue(node)` returns false. If it was an `if` instead of a `while` those statements would be executed only once.

Comment: Sorry, maybe  I'm not asking clearly.Actually, I want to ask why the author wrote it this way(while instead of if),Now I know because the spurious wakeup...but thank you, too

Answer (score 0):

Avoid unparking by the user but not by signal for robustness.